# Mixture of php shorttags

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax

I'm taking over a codeigniter project and notice the original dev uses a mixture of short tag and php tags in the views.  For example:

```
<div id="content">

        <?=show_header()?>

        <ul id="products">
            <?php if (count($products) > 0) : ?>
            <?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
             ...
</div>
```

Is this bad practice to inherit? I think it is already causing me problems in my dev environment.

EDIT: What about `<?= =>` tags INSIDE `<? php ?>` tags on some views? Like this:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($details as $detail) : ?>
<?php $detail = split(',',$detail); ?>
<?php if ($detail[0] != '') : ?>
    <li>
    <strong><?=ucwords($detail[0])?></strong> : <?=$detail[1]?>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This is whats confusing me right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bad idea. Not all installations and versions of PHP support this type of tagging, and it makes the code very hard to read.

My advice is: always use the full open-close tags: `<?php /*...*/ ?>`.

If I had been given your script to work with or fix, I would have stopped at line 3, cursed and scratched my head, because that is plainly unreadable.

Also, at line 6 & 7, I'd rather use `{` instead of `:`, also for readability.

Comment: Codeigniter has a config setting to auto convert to long form if you ever find yourself in an environment that does not support it.

Comment: I find the alternative syntax for control structures (`if:` `endif;`) way more readable when mixing PHP with HTML. Something like `<?php } ?>` looks just ugly. :]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to worry about compatibility or view preprocessing overhead, use full open tags as if short open tags never existed.

If you don't mind letting CI rewrite short open tags to full open tags, then use short open tags if you like them, but only in your view files:

```
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = true;
```

But mixing them in the same view file or CI application is just **nasty**.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, yes it is bad practice. Short tags may seem easier to use but they are not as compatible as full tags. So you should always stick to full tags.

Even if you have to use short tags at least don't mix them in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice for two reasons:

1. Lack of coding consistency
2. It will only work on web servers with the php setting `short_open_tag` set to `true`

For ultimate compatibility and portability, always use `<?php ?>`

Comment: Note that CI provides an option to rewrite short tags into full tags if necessary. Not that it's worth the overhead or anything. But I like that you used the word "ultimate" :)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the short echo tag `<?= ?>` and the standard PHP tag `<?php ?>` do different things (and are sometimes used together).  Using `<?php ?>` and its short tag equivalent `<? ?>` in a single file **is** inconsistent, and both forms of short tags are now discouraged now as they're scheduled to be [deprecated in PHP6](http://www.slideshare.net/thinkphp/php-53-and-php-6-a-look-ahead).

However. CodeIgniter processes the echo style tags as a basic template engine (much like Smarty's tags).  I strongly recommend using the echo tags in CodeIgniter views for variables, as they make the view read more clearly as HTML/XML/etc.

```
<p><?= $text ?></p>
```

Versus:

```
<p><?php echo $text ?></p>
```

The alternative is to plug in a library like Smarty, so that you're views are as close to their target file format as possible.  I've found that reducing that noise is important for debugging and maintaining views.